# ¿Como hago para paginar resultados de una query que ya ha filtrado por algún tipo de datos en Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, formularios, paginación

Tengo la siguiente duda para una página web de búsqueda de excursiones.

Primeramente, yo introduzco un formulario para filtrar por precio minimo, precio maximo, localidad, etc.

Después muestro una vista con todos los resultados según ese filtro y también  muestro la paginación con el método de **Codeigniter** de la clase pagination.

La duda me surge en que cuando pinchas sobre algún enlace de la paginación (first,1,2,3,last) la **vista** te dirige de nuevo al **controlador** al que sólo le manda un parámetro que es el número de página. El **controlador** toma sólo el dato de la página a la que quiere ir, pero no el filtro que anteriormente se ha hecho.

¿Como paso de nuevo los datos del filtro que se había hecho al principio?

¿Se hace a través de variables de sesión? ¿O se hace de otra forma?

Gracias de antemano. Un saludo.

Comment: la manera mas efica que usted puede implementa es realizar una peticion por ajax y este me llame a una public funcion filtra mediane la consulta mysql,

Comment: Puedes crear un formulario que contenga los inputs necesarios con para la búsqueda.
enseguida en javascript llama el evento submit para que cuando se ejecute realice la petición con ajax al controlador de búsqueda y envié los campos a filtra incluyendo los de numero de página y el número de registros a mostrar. en el controller crea la paginación con el número de registros y el número de página según sea el resultado de tu consulta. agregar evento en javascript que al dar clic en el link de la página actualice el input de numero de página que lo pondremos dentro del formulario de búsqueda, ens

Answer (score 0):

tengo la siguiente tabla

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-responsive table  table-striped dataTable" id="dataTable1" aria-describedby="dataTable1_info" style="margin-top: 20px;">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>ID  </th>
        <th>nombre</th>
        <th>Aciones</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <th>ID  </th>
        <th>nombre</th>
        <th>Aciones</th>
      </tr>
        </tfoot>
    <tbody aria-relevant="all" aria-live="polite" id="showdata">
    </tbody>
  </table>

<form id="myForm" action="" method="post" >
            <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="valor" required="required" name="created_at" >
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre" required="required" name="nombre" >
          <input type="submit" id="btnSave-2"   value="Guarda Cambio"  class="btn btn-primary" >

</form>
```

y tengo un javascript que me enviar el filtro por ajax, cada vez que realizo un filtro este me recibe los datos, sin la necesidad de realizar una paginación ni recargar la pagina

```
$("#myForm").submit(function() {

  var url = $('#myForm').attr('action');
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: $("#myForm").serialize(), 
  async: false,
  dataType: 'json',
   success: function(data){
   var html = '';
   var i;
   var t = $('#dataTable1').DataTable();
   t.clear();
   for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){   
   var counter = 1;
   t.row.add( [
        data[i].id,
        data[i].nombre,       

        '<a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-info item-edit" data="'+data[i].id+'">Edit</a>&nbsp;&nbsp; '+
        '<a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-danger item-delete" data="'+data[i].id+'">Delete</a>'
    ] ).draw( true );
      }
    },
    error: function(){
      alert('No se pudo carga los datos ');
    }


 });
    return false;
  });
</script>
```

tenga en cuenta tener la libreria jquery si no le va a vota error, aun estoy mirandor donde se ejecuta el codigo

y en el controlador

```
public function showAllMinorias_etnicas(){  
        $this->load->model('Minorias_etnica');
        $data = Minorias_etnica::all();
        echo json_encode($data);

    }
```